# Rails 3.1: not works upload in ckeditor in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm using gem "ckeditor", "3.7.1" in my rais project.

When I'm trying to upload an image in editor in production mode I've get:

Errno::ENOENT in Ckeditor::PicturesController#create
 No such file or directory - identify -ping /tmp/mini_magick20120608-15825-1ekfs6o.png
 Rails.root: /home/deployer/projects/myproject

RequestParameters:{"upload"=>#>,"CKEditor"=>"post_content","CKEditorFuncNum"=>"2", "langCode"=>"ru", "authenticity_token"=>"KbonuQWYYv5Ti+mly7hqOVMpxmgCv4dQEgPuUXguutE="}

In development all is ok :(
I've tried with paperclip, have the same situation - in dev all is ok, in production - not works (but without error messages).

Rails 3.1, Ubuntu OS, Passenger and nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was so simple :)

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```